# XGBoost prediction input dimensionality error

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, xgboost

I have the following model:

```
X_train_xgb, X_test_xgb, y_train_xgb, y_test_xgb = X_train.values, X_test.values, y_train.values, y_test.values 
xgb_model = xgboost.XGBRegressor()
xgb_model.fit(X_train_xgb, y_train_xgb)
```

X_train and X_test have the same count of columns. However, running

```
test_point = X_test_xgb[42]
original_model_prediction = xgb_model.predict(test_point)
```

returns

> C:/buildkite-agent/builds/buildkite-windows-cpu-autoscaling-group-i-08de971ced8a8cdc6-1/xgboost/xgboost-ci-windows/src/predictor/cpu_predictor.cc:377: Check failed: m->NumColumns() == model.learner_model_param->num_feature (1 vs. 170) : Number of columns in data must equal to trained model.

`test_point.shape` returns (170,0). I have 170 columns, so this should be ok.

This has to be some kind of dimensionality issue, as `test_point = X_test_xgb[42:43]` returns a result when used in `xgb_model.predict(test_point)` (albeit just exactly *one* result). Does .predict() expect a header row? even though I trained using an np.array?

Also, neither `X_test_xgb.T[42]` nor `test_point.T` solve the problem (as expected). Where is my mistake?

Thanks already!

Comment: When you index using a single dimension if will remove that dimension from the array, so X[42] will result in an array of shape `(0,)` (as given in your question, is this a typo?). Most sklearn models require a 2D input of shape `[batch_size, feature_size]`, so this is where your code is failing.  As you've put, to conserve this dimension you have to use `X[42:43]`, or unsqueeze it (not recommended due to ugliness): `X[42][None]`.